# Terraform official best pratice with modules and for_each?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecr, terraform-modules

I need to create about 150 AWS ECR repositories via Terraform (which I'm quite new to). I've created a little module which will make the repo and assign the policy i want to it.

My question is whether it's best practice to have the module accept a name as a variable and creates a single repo, and have code outside the module that has a `for_each` over an array of repo names, or have the module take in a list of repo names, and have the `for_each` loop itself.

Comment: What's "best" is subjective and solicits opinions. Do what is best for you in your situation.

Comment: I guess so, I just wondered if some Terraform peeps would come in and say one way is by far more widely used in which case I'd follow it

Comment: It may depend on your overall system. The number "150" seems arbitrary. Well if you would tell that you are going to create many of those "150" repositories (for example 5x150, maybe because each "150" is some group of repositories) - then yes, maybe it would be good to have a module  creating 150 repositories at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend your first option: "have the module accept a name as a variable and creates a single repo." You mentioned your module will create a repo and assign a policy to it. So you will likely have, at least, an `aws_ecr_repository` resource and an `aws_ecr_repository_policy` resource managed by your module. If you use your second option, and instead pass in a list of repo names to your module, then you will need to loop over your list of module names twice: once to make all of the `aws_ecr_repository` resources and once to make all of the `aws_ecr_repository_policy` resources. Now suppose you later realize you need to output something about each `aws_ecr_repository` from your module - yet again, you need to loop over your list of repo names to create the output. You can avoid all of those loops and keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by keeping the list of repo names external to the module.

With your second option you could also run into future issues with targeting one repo by name. Suppose you want to do a `terraform apply` and change one repo's policy. If you instantiate your module once for each repo name, and your module is called `my_repo`, and the repo name is `frontend`, then you might do:

```
terraform apply -target module.my_repo["frontend"]
```

If, however, you pass the repo names in to your module, then depending on the situation, you might have to do something like this:

```
terraform apply -target module.my_repo.aws_ecr_repository["frontend"] -target module.my_repo.aws_ecr_repository_policy["frontend"]
```

Things get more complicated if you pass in the repo names as a variable, instead of instantiating your module once for each repo name.

Comment: thanks that makes sense, it was actually when I started writing the second loop over my repo names that I was thinking there must be a nicer way